# Why does Nltk imports not need full package path

Tags: python, import, nlp, package, nltk

I've new to nltk and I notice that to create a lemmatizer object(after importing nltk package), both

```
WNlemma = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer
```

with no explicit importing of class `WordNetLemmatizer`  and

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
WNlemma = WordNetLemmatizer
```

where we explicitely import the class `WordNetLemmatizer`  would work.

I'm aware that both were referring to the class `WordNetLemmatizer` from `nltk.stem.wordnet` package, but why is it even "legal" to import without stating the full module path as in the first and second instance? Is it some nltk convention or generally a python thing? How could the class `WordNetLemmatizer` in package `wordnet` be found? Based on my shallow understanding of python imports, only

```
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
```

looks "legit" for me...

I've searched around but I couldn't find any documentation explaining this, maybe I've been searching the wrong keywords. 
This might be a noob question and please point out if it's not clear, thanks for anyone who would like to help me!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! This is a very interesting question. I can't say for sure why the aliasing works so I won't post as an answer, but you can view the [source for nltk.__init__](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/__init__.html) where it imports all of the relevant packages internally just by importing the top level package.

Comment: @G. Anderson Thanks! It's quite clear now and I'm not paranoic anymore! Feels so good!

Comment: Because explicit is better than implicit =) Try this `import this`

Answer (score 0):

This convention has to reduce amount of code you write. You can look into `nltk/__init__.py` ([https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/**init**.py](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/__init__.py)) why this is working: `WNlemma = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer`

Comment: Thanks! here's my understanding: after `import nltk`, we can invoke `nltk.stem.wordnet.WordNetLemmatizer` by `nltk.WordNetLemmatizer` as `import nltk` called `from nltk.stem import *` and `from nltk import stem ` which means all functions and class in stem package was imported and we can access them by `nltk.xxx`. Then `__init__.py` invoked when calling `...import stem` does the same thing, which allowed both of these two instances to work.

Comment: If `nltk/__init__.py` would be empty, then you could only call `import nltk; lemmatizer = nltk.stem.wordnet.WordNetLemmatizer` or `from nltk.stem import *; lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer`. But developers of nltk has decided, that using short paths in imports will save a lot of time, so they put most of subpackages(stem, pos, split, etc.) into top package (nltk) by specifing `__init__.py`